# How do I convert this code from mutate_ to mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a copy of a column based on a variable - that is, the new column's name is constant, but which one it copies changes.  This is what I would do previously:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- "mpg"

mtcars %>%
  mutate_(Target = x)
```

To receive results like this:
[image]

However, when you run this, you now receive a warning:

```
Warning message:
mutate_() is deprecated. 
Please use mutate() instead
```

It suggests looking at https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/ for guidance; I've had a quick skim, but didn't spot this as a use case in the document.  (It doesn't seem to cover the problem of converting existing code, but maybe I'm just not understanding it well enough?)

How do I move this code from `mutate_()` to `mutate()`?

Comment: I think mutate_at() works well for this sort of task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adhere to `dplyr`'s non-standard evaluation

```
mtcars %>% mutate(Target = !!sym(x))
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Target
#1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   21.0
#2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   21.0
#3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   22.8
#4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   21.4
#5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   18.7
#6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   18.1
...
```

Here `sym` takes a string as input and turns it into a symbol, which you then unquote using the bang-bang operator `!!`.

Also note that `mutate_` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate_at` and this can be also used for multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(x),   list(Target = ~ I))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rlang::sym` or base R `get`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% mutate(Target = !!rlang::sym(x))

mtcars %>% mutate(Target = get(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try basic way like this...

```
x <- mtcars$mpg
mtcars$Target <- x
```